# how to parse a json data with multiple values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

i have a multidimensional json . i want to parse it to get the values.

```
var json='{"Links":[],"RequestedObject":{"FieldContents":{"21514":{"Type":1,"IsError":false,"Value":"Saneen","FieldId":21514,"UpdateInformation":{"CreateDate":null,"UpdateDate":null,"CreateLogin":null,"UpdateLogin":null}},"21516":{"Type":1,"IsError":false,"Value":"English","FieldId":21516,"UpdateInformation":{"CreateDate":null,"UpdateDate":null,"CreateLogin":null,"UpdateLogin":null}},"21517":{"Type":1,"IsError":false,"Value":"Malayalam","FieldId":21517,"UpdateInformation":{"CreateDate":null,"UpdateDate":null,"CreateLogin":null,"UpdateLogin":null}},"21515":{"Type":2,"IsError":false,"Value":26.0,"FieldId":21515,"UpdateInformation":{"CreateDate":null,"UpdateDate":null,"CreateLogin":null,"UpdateLogin":null}},"21518":{"Type":2,"IsError":false,"Value":80.0,"FieldId":21518,"UpdateInformation":{"CreateDate":null,"UpdateDate":null,"CreateLogin":null,"UpdateLogin":null}},"21519":{"Type":2,"IsError":false,"Value":40.0,"FieldId":21519,"UpdateInformation":{"CreateDate":null,"UpdateDate":null,"CreateLogin":null,"UpdateLogin":null}},"21520":{"Type":4,"IsError":false,"Value":{"ValuesListIds":[72639],"OtherText":null},"FieldId":21520,"UpdateInformation":{"CreateDate":null,"UpdateDate":null,"CreateLogin":null,"UpdateLogin":null}},"21523":{"Type":3,"IsError":false,"Value":"2017-03-29T00:00:00","FieldId":21523,"UpdateInformation":{"CreateDate":null,"UpdateDate":null,"CreateLogin":null,"UpdateLogin":null}},"21510":{"Type":6,"FieldId":21510,"UpdateInformation":{"CreateDate":null,"UpdateDate":null,"CreateLogin":null,"UpdateLogin":null}},"21511":{"Type":21,"FieldId":21511,"UpdateInformation":{"CreateDate":null,"UpdateDate":null,"CreateLogin":null,"UpdateLogin":null}},"21512":{"Type":22,"FieldId":21512,"UpdateInformation":{"CreateDate":null,"UpdateDate":null,"CreateLogin":null,"UpdateLogin":null}},"21521":{"Type":11,"Value":null,"FieldId":21521,"UpdateInformation":{"CreateDate":null,"UpdateDate":null,"CreateLogin":null,"UpdateLogin":null}}}},"IsSuccessful":true,"ValidationMessages":[]}';
```

i have tried with JSON.parse , but no luck.

Comment: JSON.parse(json)

Comment: `JSON.parse` works just fine here.

Comment: `JSON.parse` should be able to do that. What browser are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an simple example of `JSON.parse()` and [here is document for that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```js
var json='{"Links":[],"RequestedObject":{"FieldContents":{"21514":{"Type":1,"IsError":false,"Value":"Saneen","FieldId":21514,"UpdateInformation":{"CreateDate":null,"UpdateDate":null,"CreateLogin":null,"UpdateLogin":null}},"21516":{"Type":1,"IsError":false,"Value":"English","FieldId":21516,"UpdateInformation":{"CreateDate":null,"UpdateDate":null,"CreateLogin":null,"UpdateLogin":null}},"21517":{"Type":1,"IsError":false,"Value":"Malayalam","FieldId":21517,"UpdateInformation":{"CreateDate":null,"UpdateDate":null,"CreateLogin":null,"UpdateLogin":null}},"21515":{"Type":2,"IsError":false,"Value":26.0,"FieldId":21515,"UpdateInformation":{"CreateDate":null,"UpdateDate":null,"CreateLogin":null,"UpdateLogin":null}},"21518":{"Type":2,"IsError":false,"Value":80.0,"FieldId":21518,"UpdateInformation":{"CreateDate":null,"UpdateDate":null,"CreateLogin":null,"UpdateLogin":null}},"21519":{"Type":2,"IsError":false,"Value":40.0,"FieldId":21519,"UpdateInformation":{"CreateDate":null,"UpdateDate":null,"CreateLogin":null,"UpdateLogin":null}},"21520":{"Type":4,"IsError":false,"Value":{"ValuesListIds":[72639],"OtherText":null},"FieldId":21520,"UpdateInformation":{"CreateDate":null,"UpdateDate":null,"CreateLogin":null,"UpdateLogin":null}},"21523":{"Type":3,"IsError":false,"Value":"2017-03-29T00:00:00","FieldId":21523,"UpdateInformation":{"CreateDate":null,"UpdateDate":null,"CreateLogin":null,"UpdateLogin":null}},"21510":{"Type":6,"FieldId":21510,"UpdateInformation":{"CreateDate":null,"UpdateDate":null,"CreateLogin":null,"UpdateLogin":null}},"21511":{"Type":21,"FieldId":21511,"UpdateInformation":{"CreateDate":null,"UpdateDate":null,"CreateLogin":null,"UpdateLogin":null}},"21512":{"Type":22,"FieldId":21512,"UpdateInformation":{"CreateDate":null,"UpdateDate":null,"CreateLogin":null,"UpdateLogin":null}},"21521":{"Type":11,"Value":null,"FieldId":21521,"UpdateInformation":{"CreateDate":null,"UpdateDate":null,"CreateLogin":null,"UpdateLogin":null}}}},"IsSuccessful":true,"ValidationMessages":[]}';

var obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(obj);

// retrieve particular fields

var newFieldContents = {};

for(var key in obj['RequestedObject']['FieldContents']){
  var o = obj['RequestedObject']['FieldContents'][key];
  newFieldContents[key] = {
    Value: o['Value'],
    FieldId: o['FieldId']
  }
}

console.log(newFieldContents);
```

**Update**

Add how to retrieve particular fields.

Comment: i need only some particular fields like value and FieldId

Comment: I've updated that but not all the objects contain value.